# ASP.NET MVC Session timeout with auto page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-timeout, page-refresh

There's one ASP.NET MVC page that is automatically refreshed every 2 minutes using the meta refresh tag. All other pages in the application does not have this auto refresh. The application uses SQL server sesssion state and timeout is set to 20 minutes. If user is on any page, it times out exactly after 20 minutes but if the user is on that specific page, where the auto refresh is set to every 2 minutes, it does not timeout after 20 minutes. Is there a way to auto refresh the page and also timeout the user after 20 minutes i.e basically being able to differentiate between user-driven action and system driven auto refresh?

Answer (score 1):

No. Session timeouts are sliding. Every request the user makes to the website resets the timeout. There's no way around that.